# Java code to get currently running beanstalk version label?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

From within a running Java application running on beanstalk, how can I get the beanstalk version label that is currently running?

[Multiple Edits later...]

After a few back-and-forth comments with Sony (see below), I wrote the following code which works for me now.  If you put meaningful comments in your version label when you deploy, then this will tell you what you're running.  We have a continuous build environment, so we can get our build environment to supply a label that leads to the check-in comments for the related code.  Put this all together, and your server can tell you exactly what code its running relative to your source code check-ins.  Really useful for us.  OK now I'm actually answering my own question here, but with invaluable help from Sony.  Seems a shame you can't remove the hard-coded values and query for those at runtime.

```
String getMyVersionLabel() throws IOException {
    Region region = Region.getRegion(Regions.fromName("us-west-2")); // Need to hard-code this

    AWSCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new ClasspathPropertiesFileCredentialsProvider();
    AWSElasticBeanstalkClient beanstalk = region.createClient(AWSElasticBeanstalkClient.class, credentialsProvider, null);

    String environmentName = System.getProperty("PARAM2", "DefaultEnvironmentName"); // Need to hard-code this too

    DescribeEnvironmentsResult environments = beanstalk.describeEnvironments();
    for (EnvironmentDescription ed : environments.getEnvironments()) {
        if (ed.getEnvironmentName().equals( environmentName)) {
            return "Running version " + ed.getVersionLabel() + " created on " + ed.getDateCreated());
            break;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [AWS Java SDK](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforjava/) and call this directly.

See the details of [describeApplicationVersions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/elasticbeanstalk/AWSElasticBeanstalk.html#describeApplicationVersions%28%29) API for how to get all the versions in an application.Ensure to give your regions as well (otherwise you will get the versions from the default AWS region).

Now, if you need to know the version deployed currently, you need to call additionally the [DescribeEnvironmentsRequest](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/elasticbeanstalk/AWSElasticBeanstalkClient.html#describeEnvironments%28com.amazonaws.services.elasticbeanstalk.model.DescribeEnvironmentsRequest%29). This has the **versionLabel**, which tells you the the version currently deployed.

Here again, if you need to know the environment name in the code, you need to pass it as a param to the beanstalk configuration in the aws console, and access as a PARAM.

Comment: Yes, you need to tell the region. Otherwise it gets from the default region. See if it helps.

Comment: Thanks Sony - I modified the code in the original question (see above) which gets me the right versions now (from the right region), but how do I know which one is the currently running version?

Comment: I have added more info for this in the answer above.

Comment: Thank you - I am closer but still not there.  The DescribeEnviornmentsReqest returns the list of all EnvironmentDescriptions for the current application, of which the Elastic Beanstalk cluster I'm running on is one.  One more question and hopefully that's it: How do I get the EnvironmentName of the cluster on which I'm running?  With that, I can iterate through the result from DescribeEnvironmentsRequest and find the right one.

Comment: I think you don't get it programmatically. Since it is a constant once setup, may be you can pass as a param to the beanstalk configuration in the aws console.

Comment: Thanks - I've got my code working by passing in the EnvironmentName as one of the PARAMn's of the beanstalk configuration.  Seems a shame you can't somehow query for that at run-time as that would remove that extra administration/documentation for the extra parameter.  But my code works now so many thanks!

Comment: @Danger, good that it worked. I have edited the answer to include this info as well for the benefit of new readers.